# label and text box in a single row using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to add a label and a text box in my screen using bootstrap but it is not getting inline. Not sure what am i doing wrong here. Is there any extra class that i need to use it?

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="control-group row-fluid form-inline">
                     <label for="name" class="control-label">eReview #</label>
       <div class="controls">
                     <input type="text" id="name"  class="form-control">
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You never set the `col-*-*` classes on the `label` and `.controls` fields:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group form-inline">
    <label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-3">eReview #</label>
    <div class="controls col-xs-9">
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can play around with the `*-xs-*` classes to make it fit your page however you like.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.. I will accept this answer

Comment: check your bootstrap version.

Comment: @Nedev *Checks it* ... Yup. It's there.

Comment: @J.Titus could I know what version are you using?

Comment: @J.Titus uhm... strange, why are you using row-fluid in code snippet?

Comment: @Nedev - Just copied it from sav vv's question. Didn't change anything other than the `col-*-*` classes. I agree `row-fluid` is useless here. Just took it out of the code - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**row-fluid only works in Bootstrap 2.3.2**

your code is good ONLY if your bootstrap version is 2.3.2.

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="control-group row-fluid form-inline">
                 <label for="name" class="control-label">eReview #</label>
   <div class="controls">
                 <input type="text" id="name"  class="form-control">
   </div>
 </div>
```

**if you are using Bootstrap v3 you have to use bootstrap col-* classes.**

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group form-inline">
    <label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-4">eReview #</label>
 <div class="controls col-xs-8">
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 3, then below code help you out.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="name" class="control-label col-md-4">eReview #</label>
       <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" id="name"  class="form-control" />
       </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Or you can check here
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms